# after restore from minimize WebView become disabled in javafx

Tags: javafx, webview, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

My problem is when I am restoring minimized javafx application from windows taskbar WebView become disabled.

After resize stage it becomes enabled.

> Main java Code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Browser.fxml"));
            root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Shivam Jewels ERP");
            primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                    if (t1) {
                        System.out.println("minimized:");
                    }
                }
            });
            primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        System.out.println("maximized:");
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> My JavaFX Code Is:

```
public class BrowserController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private WebView browser;
    @FXML
    private GridPane grdPn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        browser.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        browser.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
        webEngine.load("http://192.168.2.6:4200");
    }

}
```

> This is my CSS Code:

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

> This is my FXML Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="382.0" prefWidth="353.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.BrowserController">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="grdPn" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="135.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <WebView fx:id="browser" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>`enter code here`
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Can you provide fxml and css files?

Comment: Thanks for your response see my last update for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a JDK bug reported multiple times [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169776), [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166677) and [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087997). The behavior you described happens when `satge` is maximized.

This bug was scheduled to be fixed in JDK9 but according to [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166677) is also going to be fixed in JDK8u122:

> Approved to backport to 8u-dev for 8u122.

JDK 8u122 [is planned](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/releases/8u122.html) to be released in January 2017 so it won't be long before we can use it but for now you can download and use early access release from [JDK 8u122 early access page](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

I myself downloaded it and tested the code and fortunately problem no longer exists.

Comment: After changing version of java it's working for me.
Thanks

Comment: This appears to be happening again on windows 10 only.